# Could I simulate the implementation of memory components

Tags: computer-architecture, simulation

I am currently reading the IEEE paper [A Memory-Efficient Parallel String Matching
Architecture for High-Speed Intrusion Detection](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpls/abs_all.jsp?arnumber=1705612) by Kai Zheng,  Bin Liu,  Xin Zhang, and  Yunhao Liu.

In the paper they propose a model for
 a memory-efficient multiple-character-approaching architecture
consisting of multiple parallel DFAs.

I have read the paper and I have understood to an extent.

But when I think of implementation, could I simulate the SRAM, LE,BCAM etc.. as in the case of a network simulator (NS-2,OPNET,OMNET).[image]

Comment: Google: "Circuit simulator". There are plenty out there. Spice is an oldy but a goody.

Comment: Is the graphic taken from the paper? If so, please check it's license and credit it accordingly.

Comment: Yes, one could using _discrete event simulation_ which is what network simulators use.

Comment: Aside from implementation issues, I fail to see why it should *not* work. Without further information/insight, is this a constructive ontopic question?

Answer (score 1):

You can simulate the architecture using a **hardware-description language**.

Try VHDL (http://esd.cs.ucr.edu/labs/tutorial/) or Verilog ( http://www.asic-world.com/verilog/veritut.html) two of the most popular hardware description languages.